# Replit Database. How would I embed the curl commands of the Replit Database into my php web server code?

Tags: php, database, replit

I am creating a sign up page on my PHP web server on replit that involves the replit default database. I know that there are language clients for python, node, and go. How do I embed the curl commands into the PHP code. Currently, I am using the shell exec command to execute curls on the online shell. The curl commands I am using from repl.it are

```
curl $REPLIT_DB_URL -d 'key=value'

curl $REPLIT_DB_URL/key
    
curl -XDELETE $REPLIT_DB_URL/key
    
curl "$REPLIT_DB_URL?prefix=key"
```

They are used for setting keys to values, getting a key's value, deleting a key, and listing all keys respectively.
When I copy these commands and paste them into a PHP file like this,

```
<?php


$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
curl $REPLIT_DB_URL -d '$email=$password';
curl $REPLIT_DB_URL/$email;

?>
```

I get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '$REPLIT_DB_URL' (T_VARIABLE)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there any other info I need to provide because I am getting downvoted for no known reason without any feedback?

Comment: You are getting downvoted because you haven't shown any attempt at research or provided an attempt at a solution that you need help with. PS: a simple web search for 'php curl' should lead you to the inbuilt PHP curl library. https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: I couldn't really find anything there. The one Im looking for involves key-value databases. I will edit my question to show this.

Comment: A curl is a curl. You want to call a database via curl from PHP. Use the PHP curl library. Anything specific to your database is just URL, headers and body. I have quite successfully written trash-grade 'drivers' to call GraphQL and Elasticsearch services from PHP applications using only PHP's curl library. It works fine. Heck, go deep enough into any real driver library in PHP that calls a HTTP service and you'll find the curl commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just paste console commands into PHP code and expect them to work. The error you are getting is that it doesn't understand what `$REPLIT_DB_URL` is.

You are going to have to convert your console commands into PHP code.

```
$ch = curl_init('http://url-to-your-database-server');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{$email}={$password}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === false) {
    // handle the error here
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Whether you need to `json_encode` the body (email and password pair) or not is up to how your database accepts the body. Your raw `curl` lines suggest maybe not. You may also need to `json_decode` the `$result`, maybe not.

Note that I have kept the `$ch` handler open for the error handling, you can get the code and response for an error with

```
curl_error($ch)
curl_errno($ch)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];


$retval = null;

//adds key and the data
exec('curl $REPLIT_DB_URL -d \''.$email.'='.$password.'\'');

//gets the key 
exec('curl $REPLIT_DB_URL/'.$email, $retval);
echo $retval[0] . "<br>";  //prints data the 


$retval=null;

//gets all keys that have the $email (like @gmail.com and all emails with Gmail domain come up) in it, as a list
exec('curl "$REPLIT_DB_URL?prefix='.$email.'"', $retval);

foreach ($retval as $keyname) { 
  $retval=null;
  exec('curl $REPLIT_DB_URL/'.$keyname, $retval); 
  echo $keyname .": ". $retval[0]."<br>";  //prints data the 
  
}

//deletes the key 
exec('curl -XDELETE $REPLIT_DB_URL/'.$email);

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem and I finally solved it. Here is the steps:

- open Replit's terminal (shell) and execute this command: `echo $REPLIT_DB_URL` to get the database URL.
- copy [ReplitDB.php](https://github.com/dannsbass/replit-php-db/blob/master/ReplitDB.php) from [Replit Database for PHP](https://github.com/dannsbass/replit-php-db).
- include or require it to your code, here is the code:

```php
require __DIR__ .'/ReplitDB.php';

use \Dannsbass\ReplitDB;

$db = new ReplitDB(REPLIT_DB_URL); // get from terminal: echo $REPLIT_DB_URL

// set your data 
$db->set_data('email', $your_email);
$db->set_data('password', $your_password);

// get all data keys
echo $db->get_keys();

// retrieve a specified data by its key
echo $db->get_data('email');
```

Please check [Replit Database for PHP](https://github.com/dannsbass/replit-php-db) for documentation.